# When shoud I use p/c namespaces and when property/constructor-arg elements (Spring)?

Tags: java, spring

I know that:

- Using p-namespace and c-namespace is less flexible, because you cannot use them with names that end with Ref and you cannot use a list/map/properties/set as the value.
- Using p-namespace implies an overhead at run time (I am not sure about c-namespace).
- p-namespace and c-namespace are not defined in a schema or a XSD file, but I do not know what this practically means.
- p/c namespaces are much more readable and short.

is there a convention about this?

Comment: What do you mean by p-namespace overhead at runtime?

Comment: @chenrui The Spring Reference says "[p-namespace] is more succinct; however, typos are discovered at runtime rather than design time" here's the link: [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-value-element)

Answer (score 0):

You can mix then: Just use the p/c namespace as long as it works. When you have a problem with one bean, then switch over to explicit propert/contructor declaration.

Comment: I also was thinking on doing it at the beginning, but I found this in the Spring Reference about the decision [[link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-p-namespace)]: "We recommend that you choose your approach carefully and communicate this to your team members, to avoid producing XML documents that use all three approaches at the same time" so I assumed that using both is a bad practice (I do not know why it says three approaches).

Comment: I guess that  the third approach is Java Based Configuration. My hit does not violate that rule: it states that you prefere c/p over properties, and only fall back to properties when c/p does not work -- the Problem with mixing in the sense of the reference documentation (to my understanding) is that it is not recommended to mix them without any rules, so one programmer is using properties while an other would use c/p for the same configuration.

Comment: Java Based Configuration makes sense, thanks. I understand and like your point. I will use it. You should post it as an answer, not a comment.